# What should I do next to find a car brand inside my car index I created above?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    string indexcar[5];
// declare index
    indexcar[0] = "Volvo";
    indexcar[1] = "Mazada";
    indexcar[2] = "Toyota";
    indexcar[3] = "Tesla";
    indexcar[4] = "Honda";

// print index
printf("Car index included: \n");
printf("%s\n", indexcar[0]);
printf("%s\n", indexcar[1]);
printf("%s\n", indexcar[2]);
printf("%s\n", indexcar[3]);
printf("%s\n", indexcar[4]);



string findcar = get_string(" Car brand to find: ");
// prompt user input

// IF else statement
if ((findcar = indexcar[0]))
{
    printf("Volvo\n");
}

else if((findcar = indexcar[1]))
{
    printf("Mazada\n");
}
else if((findcar = indexcar[2]))
{
    printf("Toyota\n");
}
else if((findcar = indexcar[3]))
{
    printf("Tesla\n");
}
else if((findcar = indexcar[4]))
{
    printf("Honda\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Can't find your car brand\n");
}
}
```

What I do wrong in my code to find a car brand in my car index? When I debugged, the value I typed is different from the else if statement I made. Ex: " Typed: Honda, Value = 0x0980", "If-else statement value= 08x2948", what should I do to input a car brand and if the statement is true, print "Car brand name" and if not, it's print " Can't find your car brand"?

Comment: I guess you need [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) instead of `==` or `-`

Comment: I don't have CS50.h installed on my system; however, that is not the issue.  In your various if tests, you need to use "==" instead of "=".  Having just one equals sign is just replacing variable findcar with the string variable at each test.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if`s you are replacing the value, and not comparing it, change the `=` to `==`, like @Ed Heal and @NoDakker said.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    string indexcar[5];
// declare index
    indexcar[0] = "Volvo";
    indexcar[1] = "Mazada";
    indexcar[2] = "Toyota";
    indexcar[3] = "Tesla";
    indexcar[4] = "Honda";

// print index
printf("Car index included: \n");
printf("%s\n", indexcar[0]);
printf("%s\n", indexcar[1]);
printf("%s\n", indexcar[2]);
printf("%s\n", indexcar[3]);
printf("%s\n", indexcar[4]);



string findcar = get_string(" Car brand to find: ");
// prompt user input

// IF else statement
if ((findcar == indexcar[0])) // note the change from = to ==
{
    printf("Volvo\n");
}

else if((findcar == indexcar[1])) // note the change from = to ==
{
    printf("Mazada\n");
}
else if((findcar == indexcar[2])) // note the change from = to ==
{
    printf("Toyota\n");
}
else if((findcar == indexcar[3])) // note the change from = to ==
{
    printf("Tesla\n");
}
else if((findcar == indexcar[4])) // note the change from = to ==
{
    printf("Honda\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Can't find your car brand\n");
}
}
```